# What is the best way to populate container with data from link?

Tags: javascript, css, iframe, sidebar

I have not been able to wrap my brain around how to call information from a link (In my domain) to populate a sidebar container that I wish to show other sources for the same information.

It would look much like a "related news", but would not be automated and instead use links that are included in code that calls it from either clicking the link (most likely), or having it loaded after the link is loaded in to an Iframe.

The site is built around CSS, but I assume I will need javascript to accomplish this task. Am I going about this the correct way or should I look at the problem from a different angle?

Comment: I think you're talking about an "include".

Comment: Check out the jQuery load() function http://api.jquery.com/load

Comment: Looking in to it now...cooking dinner so I'll have to try to integrate it in to my site after, but it looks very promising. Thank you for the heads up. Sorry about the noob question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a basic example. When you click the link the jQuery will load content.html into "xyz" div.

HTML...

```
<a id="abc" href="#">Load Info</a>
<div id="xyz"></div>
```

jQuery...

```
$('#abc').click(function() {
    $('#xyz').load('content.html');
});
```

Here is a demo where I used the html() function instead but it's the same basic idea...

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wdm954/JBWxr/1/